# Braintree JS SDK + Rails integration

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, braintree

I've followed [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/integrate-braintree-payments-rails/) integration almost word for word for my Rails 5 app to integrate Braintree SDK.  All seems to be going well except my form will not show the default basic form to collect credit card info that comes with Dropin-UI.   It just has the purchase button, but that's it.

Console error says `Uncaught ReferenceError: braintree is not defined`

Here is code: 
View (transactions/new):

```
<section class="container nav-main-override">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-container radius-box glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
         <h2 class="mbs">New Transaction</h2>
         <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
         <p>Please enter your payment details:</p>
         <div id="dropin"></div>
         <%=submit_tag "Pay #{current_order.total_price}$", class: "button mt1" %>
         <%end%>
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

transactions controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
      gon.client_token = generate_client_token
  end

  def generate_client_token
      Braintree::ClientToken.generate
    end

end
```

application.js

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function(){
     braintree.setup(gon.client_token, 'dropin', { container: 'dropin'});
});
```

Comment: Can you add the code from the `transactions.js.coffee` file to your question? that part initializes the Braintree JS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include this:

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
```

in your application layout.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I did that for sure and still nothing.

Comment: `braintree.js` is a hotlinked version of the JS v2 library which stops at version 2.15.7. I recommend using `"https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.32.1.min.js"` instead.